# Phonegap: how to get the actual width&height of a captured video

Tags: cordova, video-capture

I was trying to get the width & height of a captured video via phonegap. No matter if my iphone was in portrait or landscape when capturing the video, the width/height output was always 480x360. Any idea why?

```
 captureSuccess: function(mediaFiles) {
    var path, mediaFile;
    path = mediaFiles[0].fullPath;
    mediaFile = mediaFiles[0];
    mediaFile.getFormatData(function(mediaFileData) {
        console.log(mediaFileData);
        //output for mediaFileData : {"width":480,"duration":1.478333,"bitrate":0,"codecs":null,"height":360}
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("<video/>").attr("src", "VIDEO_PATH").on('loadedmetadata', function() {
    var dimensions = [this.videoWidth, this.videoHeight];
    alert(dimensions);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but the loadedmetadata event wasn't triggered. I guess the video has to be loaded onto the page in order for that to work.

Comment: The above code is worked for me. pls check that you are getting the correct video url.